# is it possible to parse a multi-dimensional array with form inputs along with predefined values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

PHP supports me to do this:

`<input name=array[] type=text>`

what I want to do is using the same principle construct a multi-dimensional array. The scenario is I have lots of questions, some questions with multiple answers (checkboxes).

I want to essentially parse the values of all questions in one array, however along with the question id as a value. So on the other side I can essentially store to my database, the answer with the question id.

i want the array to be contain this essentially:

[0] question_id | answer
[1] question_id | answer

so far I can do this: (note this is just for an example, not my actual code)

```
<form method=post action="testing.php">
<input name="response[q1][]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[q2][]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[q3][]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[q3][]" type=text value=''>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

however q1 is obviously the key. I want it to be a predefined value. I am new to this so its all confusing me a bit. If someone can understand what I am trying to do and knows how please help me :D

many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an array of question id:-

```
$questions = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

You can loop through this array of question id and create input fields:-

```
foreach($questions as $key => $question) {
    ?>
    <input name="response[$key][<?php echo $question ?>]" type="text" value=''>
    <?php
}
```

So, the input fields will be:-

```
<input name="response[0][1]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[1][2]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[2][3]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[3][4]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[4][5]" type=text value=''>
```

The above input fields are in the following format:-

```
<input name="response[AutoIncrementValue][QuestionId]" type=text value=''>
```

When you submit the form, the post array is as below:-

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => as
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => asdf
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => asdf
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [4] => asdfadf
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [5] => asdfadf
                )
        )
)
```

Now the post array is in the following format (as you have desired in your question):-

> [0] question_id | answer
>
> [1] question_id | answer

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried this, and response[] is just a key pointing to response[][] if that makes sense. Its not a value as far I can understand.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check if it helps with your requirement.